# Determine a linear approximation of $f$ where $z=f(x,y)$ and $e^{z} = xyz$ at $(e^{2}, 1/2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $z = f(x, y)$ be the function clearly defined by the equation
$e^{z} = xyz$, determine the linear approximation of $z$ around the point $(e^2,1/2)$

**What I know**: I know I can use $L\left(x,y\right)=f\left({x}_{0},{y}_{0}\right)+{f}_{x}\left({x}_{0},{y}_{0}\right)\left(x-{x}_{0}\right)+{f}_{y}\left({x}_{0},{y}_{0}\right)\left(y-{y}_{0}\right)$, however I don't know how to use the function $e^{z} = xyz$.

Comment: $f_x(x,y)e^{f(x,y)} = yf(x,y) + xyf_x(x,y)$, etc.

Comment: @Aruralreader Sorry, can you expand on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit differentiation of $e^z = xyz$ gives:

$$e^z dz = yz\ dx + xz\ dy + xy\ dz$$
$$xyz\ dz = yz\ dx + xz\ dy + xy\ dz$$
$$(xyz - xy)\ dz = yz\ dx + xz\ dy$$
$$dz = \frac{yz}{xyz - xy} dx + \frac{xz}{xyz - xy} dy$$
$$dz = \frac{z}{x(z-1)} dx + \frac{z}{y(z-1)} dy$$

So, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{z}{x(z-1)}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{z}{y(z-1)}$

Now, at $x = e^2$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}$, we have $e^z = (e^2)(\frac{1}{2})z$, which is satisfied by $z = 2$.  Therefore:

$$z \approx f(e^2, \frac{1}{2}) + f_x(e^2, \frac{1}{2})(x - e^2) + f_y(e^2, \frac{1}{2})(y - \frac{1}{2})$$
$$z \approx 2 + \frac{2}{e^2(2-1)}(x - e^2) + \frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}(2-1)}(y - \frac{1}{2})$$
$$z \approx 2 + \frac{2}{e^2}(x - e^2) + 4(y - \frac{1}{2})$$
$$z \approx 2 + \frac{2}{e^2}x - 2 + 4y - 2$$
$$z \approx \frac{2}{e^2}x + 4y - 2$$